# how to install dependencies with specific version while installing one module in npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, package

I want to install dependencies with specific version while installing one module.

Let's say I want to install react-virtualized-select module. It has a dependency on react-virtualized module. 
So when I run  'npm install react-virtualized-select', It installs latest version(9.11.0) of 'react-virtualized' module. But I want to install specific version (9.9.0) of 'react-virtualized' module.

I tried doing below in package.json

```
 "peerDependencies": {
   "react-virtualized-select/react-virtualized": "9.9.0"
 },
```

but shows below message.

```
 +-- react-virtualized@9.11.1
 `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-virtualized-select/react-virtualized@9.9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way!

Syntax,

```
npm i packageName@versionNumber
```

For example,

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons@6.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

run command

```
npm install --save react-virtualized@9.9.0
```

Comment: It does not work when I only install react-virtualized-select.

Comment: uninstall and remove it from `packages.json` and run this command. This will also install `react-virtualized-select` with it.

Comment: How does that work ? react-virtualized is required for 'react-virtualized-select' but not vice-versa.

Comment: You  can see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized that `react-virtualized-select` is one of the **dependents** of `react-virtualized` not a **dependency** of it.

Comment: but I want to use react-virtualized-select which is not a part of react-virtualized module. Please understand my point.

Comment: Run `npm install --save react-virtualized-select` after running the first command to avoid getting the unwanted version of `react-virtualized` module.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can share why you want another version of a dependency. 
A module controls dependencies through its package.json. It knows which version it depends on and installs that version. Overriding that dependency may give you unwanted results. If you want another version installed, you can add that in your package json.

```
react-virtualized-select: '^9.11.0',
react-virtualized: '<version>'
```